# JobScheduler run job only ONCE, every time the conditions are met

Tags: android, job-scheduling

I want to run a job every time the device is `Charging` & `ON WIFI`. This job has to run only **ONCE**, every time these conditions are met. Meaning that if I leave the phone charging and on wifi the job should not repeat itself. Only when I unplug and replug the job will execute again.

```
        builder.setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_UNMETERED)
                .setRequiresCharging(true)
                .setPeriodic(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(10))
                .setPersisted(true)
```

Job scheduler provides methods like `setPeriodic` but that will run my job every X amount of time. Not really what I want.

Questions:

- Is it possible to achieve this using job scheduler? The documentation on this is pretty scare.

Comment: Not a duplicate, you must have only read the title. I have updated the title to better represent the quesiton

Comment: Well, the answer is no, so the remainder of your question (which you also revised out) is indeed perfectly answered by the other question.